# Deselecting default screen shots option using Apple Script

Tags: applescript, screenshot

I am trying to make an apple script through which I can deselect this option:

System Preferences > Hardware > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts > Screen Shots > Save picture of selected area as a file

Can anyone suggest me some sample script for it?

Thanks,

Miraaj

Answer (score 0):

System Preferences are not scriptable by default. You will have to use GUI Scripting, but that will be a little bit different for everyone depending on what preferences they have installed. There is a an excellent example over at [www.macosxautomation.com](http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/uiscripting/index.html) that will get you started.

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit late to this but, here's what worked for me:

```
     tell application "System Preferences"
       --activate
       reveal anchor "shortcutsTab" of pane id "com.apple.preference.keyboard"
     end tell

     tell application "System Events" to tell process "System Preferences"
        select row 4 of table 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of tab group 1 of window 1
        repeat with r in rows of outline 1 of scroll area 2 of splitter group 1 of tab group 1 of window 1
          click checkbox 1 of UI element 1 of r
        end repeat
     end tell

     quit application "System Preferences"
```

Note this disable all checkboxes and not just "Save picture of selected area as a file". To disable just that replace the repeat block with:

```
click checkbox 1 of UI element 1 of row 4 of outline 1 of scroll area 2 of splitter group 1 of tab group 1 of window 1
```

You can enable or disable any other screenshot shortcut by replacing `row 4` with the row number of the correct shortcut